# How can I use the new context package from Go like I would use gorilla context library?

Tags: go

Go has come with a new package called context and with recent versions (Go 1.7 I think) we should be able to use it in the same way as gorilla/context package:

http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context

With gorilla context you can very easily set and get variables that are relevant to a request, it's handlers, and middlewares.

To set a value in gorilla context is really easy:

```
func handleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    context.Set(r, "foo", "bar")
}
```

To get the value we can do:

```
func handleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    val := context.Get(r, "foo")
}
```

I understand that we can use this in middlewares so that the next middleware can use variables that were set in previous middleware. I would like to be able to do this with Go context package.

I understand that to get a value is quite simple like this:

```
func handleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Context().Value("foo"))
}
```

But I have no idea how to set the value. It was not very intuitive for me and I don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of the context interface [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context). The short answer is: use [WithValue](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) to add a value to a context.

Comment: WithValue takes in a context as parameter, and returns a context. I don't understand how to use it. It is not as simple as the gorilla context package where you just set and get.

Comment: When you use WithValue, you're creating a new context with your current context as the parent. This way each layer of middleware can add context that is visible to it and to any subsequent layers. [context.Background](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Background) can be used as your top-level context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Exploring the context package](https://medium.com/@ambot/exploring-the-context-package-db30a818d563#.1mczb58pf)", using [`WithValue`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) and the context associated to the Request:

> ### Middleware
>
> Middleware in Go refers to an http handler which wraps around a multiplexer. There are several 3rd party middleware solutions (such as negroni), but really the standard library supports a very similar pattern. The use of a Context in the request allows us to hold data in the request.
>
> See the example code for [invocation](https://github.com/laher/context-example/blob/master/main.go#L49) and [definition](https://github.com/laher/context-example/blob/eaf242039e9825ad8b4d379d4baf4df5eba21b35/main.go#L134-L145).

```
func putClientIPIntoContext(r *http.Request) context.Context {
    ci := r.RemoteAddr
    fwd := r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")
    if fwd != "" {
        ci = fwd
    }
    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ClientIPKey, ci)
    return ctx
}
```

> The Context can store request-scoped variables.
> It’s useful when writing ‘middleware’, but it’s a little bit ‘anti-pattern’ — it’s a bit magical, because it’s not type-safe.

See more at "[Pitfalls of context values and how to avoid or mitigate them in Go](https://www.calhoun.io/pitfalls-of-context-values-and-how-to-avoid-or-mitigate-them/)".

> [The example below](https://gist.github.com/joncalhoun/ebf07cb652a91af6b481afc912ab8bff) only shows how you might use the authentication logic from above to verify that when a user is logged in when visiting any page with a path prefix of `/dashboard/`.
> A similar approach could be used to verify that a user is an admin before allowing them access to any page with a path prefix of `/admin/`.

```
func requireUser(next http.Handler) http.Handler {  
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := lookupUser(r)
    if user == nil {
      // No user so redirect to login
      http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
      return
    }
    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", user)
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
  })
}

func main() {  
  dashboard := http.NewServeMux()
  dashboard.HandleFunc("/dashboard/hi", printHi)
  dashboard.HandleFunc("/dashboard/bye", printBye)

  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  // ALL routes that start with /dashboard/ require that a 
  // user is authenticated using the requireUser middleware
  mux.Handle("/dashboard/", requireUser(dashboard))
  mux.HandleFunc("/", home)

  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", addRequestID(mux))
}
```

As [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) comments, use Context wisely, like [Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/about) suggest in "[`Context` is for cancelation](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation)"

Comment: @Alex, [see also](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation).

Comment: Thanks! The article: "Pitfalls of context values and how to avoid or mitigate them in Go" that you suggested had code snippet that made me understand it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alex Great. I have included the relevant code snippet in the answer